# Disable Auto-Renaming of Columns in DevExtreme

Tags: reactjs, devexpress, devextreme

According to the DevExpress website [Link](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/UI_Components/DataGrid/Columns/Customize_Column_Headers/):

"The DataGrid generates column headers based on the names of data fields by default. For example, if a data field is "fullName", the column header text is "Full Name"."

The link also shows how to customize the column names. However, this has to be hard-coded, and my column headers can take on different types of values, depending on what data is uploaded.

How can I disable this renaming (e.g. have the column header display as "fullName")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reply was provided by the DevExpress Support Center:

"DataGrid does not have a property that allows you to disable this behavior. However, you can reset a column's caption to its data field in the [customizeColumns](https://js.devexpress.com/DevExtreme/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#customizeColumns) callback. For example:

```
function customizeColumns(columns) {
  columns.forEach((column) => {
    column.caption = column.dataField;
  })
}
```

See the following sample that demonstrates this solution: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/madobyte/pen/poLWXaX). Although it is written in jQuery, it also applies to ASP.NET Core."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to disable it but you can go into localization under the model, and set a fix text for it. You can also set localized text, with the CaptionHelper class. With that class you can change the text depending on what situation is happening.
[CaptionHelper Class](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/DevExpress.ExpressApp.Utils.CaptionHelper)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).